# Image Adapter load method - use Bitmap Array?

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader, picasso

For the below - I don not have the URL of the image!  I cannot use the URL.

If I am downloading images from the internet into a Bitmap array like this:

```
 Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(file.getReadStream());
 //add to the Bitmap Array
 images.add(image);
```

Can this be sent to Picasso (or any other Image loader like UIL?)

I know I can display the images in my Adapter but I am getting out of memory issues. And I thought Picasso could take care of this and the caching etc.

This will not work as it will not accept a Bitmap source.  Is there any other library to do this?

```
Picasso.with(context).load(images.get(position)).resize(60, 60).error(R.drawable.error_icon).into(holder.iconImage);
```

Comment: try UniversalImageLoader library

Comment: it doesnt take an array of Bitmaps afaik

Comment: if u want to display images , then pass the array of url and using ImageLoader library u can display your bitmaps

Comment: See the first line of my post, I can't retrieve the URLs, I can only get the bitmaps. Currently I am decoding them into an array using bitmap factory

Comment: okay but you can get URI to the file u are using to decode bitmap !! and u can use that

Comment: Images are stored in the Bitmap Array pix (see below), the bitmaps are stored in memory....................    :                                              file = fileSystem.openThumbnail(fileInfo.path, ThumbSize.XS, ThumbFormat.PNG);

Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(file.getReadStream());
pix.add(image);

Comment: u can use "fileInfo.path" to load the images using UImageLoader

Comment: fileInfo is not local, and is not a URL.  It is a dropbox path.